# Filter Eloquent results Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make a member search with some filter options.

I tried **filter()**, but I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function filter() on array
```

It works when I use only one filter, because it only returns the id's.
Is their a way I can use filter() multiple times, this is my code:

```
$members = User::all();

if ($has_avatar) {
    $members = $members->filter(function ($member) {
        //Avatar is not empty, other wise false
        return ($member->avatar != "") ? true : false;
    });
}
if ($is_online) {
    $members = $members->filter(function ($member) {
        //User is now online, other wise false
        return ($member->is_online == 1) ? true : false;
    });
}
```

Or is there a other way to achieve this?

Comment: Hmm, you could try using collect();  `$members = collect(User::all());` or see my answer for more appropriate solution

Answer (score 5):

As documentation says at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-filter, this method returns only a plain array.

You could try:

```
$members->filter(function ($member) {
    return ($member->avatar != "") && ($member->is_online == 1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that in Laravel 5.2 the `all()` method returns an array now.

Try using:

```
$members = User::get();

if ($has_avatar) {
    $members = $members->filter(function ($member) {
        //Avatar is not empty, other wise false
        return ($member->avatar != "") ? true : false;
    });
}
if ($is_online) {
    $members = $members->filter(function ($member) {
        //User is now online, other wise false
        return ($member->is_online == 1) ? true : false;
    });
}
```